# how should I add some action Items to a dialog?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-dialog, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

I have a custom dialog which I want to add it some action items with icon like android calender .

[image: android calender with dialog with action items]

here is manifest code to give theme to my activity :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".FileChooser"
        android:label="FileChooser"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog"  tools:ignore="NewApi">
    </activity>
```

and in FileChooser.java :

```
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
 {
        MenuItem camramnu= menu.add(0,0,0,"Take a picture");
        {
            camramnu.setIcon(R.drawable.camera);
            camramnu.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
        return true;
 }
```

and it never show the icon !

how can I do it ?

Comment: Is the "Take a picture" text at least appearing?

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock for the ActionBar? or just the native API

Comment: sorry !
im really sorry , yes it does !
it appears !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem - you've got an options menu, but from your included image there's already what looks like a contextual action bar menu running, with "Done" and "Cancel"

Maybe you need to set your menu options on that

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

In that case,

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

// Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// Called each time the action mode is shown. Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
// may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false; // Return false if nothing is done
}

// Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_share:
            shareCurrentItem();
            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

// Called when the user exits the action mode
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    mActionMode = null;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

is your menu within a fragment?  In a fragment you have to use
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);